# StreamWriter writing 2 characters per character over Ascii value 128. How to write just 1 character?

Tags: c#, encoding, streamwriter

I am re-writing some legacy software.

This legacy software creates files using bcp using data from sql server.

The new software has replaced the bcp method and uses StreamWriter in a C# app to create the file.

I need to match the legacy output and the new output exactly as we cannot introduce any difference into the files.

I am having trouble with characters above (char)128. Anything above 128 writes 2 characters for every original character.

So within the legacy file, this character appears ª

When I try to write this character using StreamWriter, it is written as Âª

In this case the character value is 170 (this may be different depending on the encoding being used).

I have tried using various encodings with the StreamWriter, I have tried UTF7, UTF8, even UTF32, I've used encoding 1252 too, but all produce 2 characters.

All other characters below 128 are written as one character as required. I simply need to write a single character of (char)170, but I can't find how to do this with the StreamWriter, as by default it produces two characters.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments.  TyCobb, here's the code, it's quite basic

`var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(someBaseStream,Encoding.UTF8);//.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));`

Then to simplify : `streamWriter.Write("ª");` // Although this character usually appears in the middle of a string variable.

Comment: ASCII `170` is `¬`, but `0170` is Unicode ª. Make sure your encoding is ASCII. It sounds like you want ASCII and not Unicode. Please add code to your question so we can see how you are writing the file. ASCII is 1 byte per character and Unicode is 2 bytes per character. That usually is why it looks like 2 characters instead of one. By default encoding is UTF-16.

Comment: @TyCobb `0170` is also `ª` in `Windows-1252`.

Comment: @spodger Ah, good to know. Thanks

Comment: @TyCobb I think you're on the right lines though. `UTF-8` would write all characters up to 128 (ASCII) as one byte but then use 2,3 or 4 bytes. Which seems coincidental to me.

Comment: In fact if you write 170 in `UTF-8` it will actually write 194 170 which is `Âª` in Windows-1252 but `ª` in UTF-8.

Comment: You can run bcp from c# instead of re-inventing the wheel.  What I normally do is to create a bat file with the bcp commands, then run the .bat using Process Class in c#.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  TyCobb, here's the code, it's quite basic

`var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(someBaseStream,Encoding.UTF8);//.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));`

Then to simplify : `streamWriter.Write("ª");` // Although this character usually appears in the middle of a string variable.

Comment: Well, you are very confused about *something*, 1252 never generates more than one byte for a character.  And utf8 certainly generates 2 for that glyph, no surprise there.  Only sensible advice I can think of is to double-check the assumptions, use a good hex viewer and use Encoding.Default

Comment: spodger, you're spot on, that's exactly what is happening. In the old file I simply get the 170, but using the StreamWriter, I always get 194 170.

Comment: Good advise, thanks Hans Passant

Comment: You need to compare both files on the binary level, thus please use hex viewer to compare the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write 170 in UTF-8 it will actually write 194 170 which is Âª in Windows-1252 but ª in UTF-8

Using

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(someBaseStream,Encoding.UTF8);
```

will definitely cause your problem.

However, your commented out alternative is not quite correct; `.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));`

It should be `.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));` note the capital W.

Or to remove any doubt use

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(someBaseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Comment: This is it! Strangely no error when using the lower case w, but it has worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem; glad to be of help!